# How to filter dataframe against reference with varying conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to filter for grouped rows based on multiple conditions (some arbitrary number of comparisons that may contain one or two conditions) like so:

We begin with a test dataframe, a reference table containing relevant conditions, and test for the presence of all conditions within a group.

```
library(tidyverse)

test_case = tribble(
  ~id, ~value,
  1, 'A',
  1, 'B',
  2, 'C',
  3, 'C',
  3, 'D',
  4, 'E',
  4, 'F'
)

reference_table = tribble(
  ~var1, ~var2,
  'A', 'NA',
  'B', 'NA',
  'C', 'D',
  'D', 'E',
  'E', 'F'
)
```

I expect to filter `test_case` against `reference_table` such that groups in `test_case` with values 
1) satisfying `var1` only when `var2` is `NA` are present or 2) satisfying both conditions when both `var1` and `var2` are defined. So in this contrived example, the group containing `id` 2 will not be present in the filtered `test_case` because while it contains value C, it requires both C and D to be present. On the other hand, id 3 meets filter requirements because it contains both C and D, matching the third row in the reference table.

```
filtered_test_case = tribble(
  ~id, ~value,
  1, 'A',
  1, 'B',
  3, 'C',
  3, 'D',
  4, 'E',
  4, 'F'
)
```

I've attempted something like

```
test_case %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(value %in% reference_table$var1, value %in% reference_table$var2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

which does not perform the way I expected. The idea was to demand one or both (where valid) conditions match. I think I can understand why after applying

```
test_case %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(var1_check = if_else(value %in% reference_table$var1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(var2_check = if_else(value %in% reference_table$var2, TRUE, FALSE))
```

I think I can see a convoluted way of applying `case_when` logic to achieve my goal, but I'm looking for a succinct way of doing so.

Comment: I would recommend clarifying your logic. Why is `id = 3` not  filtered out? It contains `var1 = "D"` but not `var1 = "E"`.

Comment: I've added the following statement -- "On the other hand, id 3 meets filter requirements because it contains both C and D, matching the third row in the reference table." Hopefully this clarifies?

Comment: Why `id = 4` is selected? No rows in `reference_table` have E and F or only E or only F ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @RonakShah, in translating to generic data from my actual case I forgot to include that. `id = 4` is now selected because it matches both conditions. If `id = 4` had only E, for example, it would not have been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `NA`'s in `reference_table` are not real `NA`s they are string `"NA"`'s. Let's change that :

```
reference_table[reference_table == 'NA'] <- NA
```

After that, we can write a function that will select a group if any row in `reference_table` is completely present in the group `value`.

```
select_rows <- function(ref_tab, value) {
   any(apply(ref_tab, 1, function(x) all(na.omit(x) %in% value)))
}
```

We can then apply this function for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

test_case %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(select_rows(reference_table, value))


#    id value
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 A    
#2     1 B    
#3     3 C    
#4     3 D    
#5     4 E    
#6     4 F
```